# sending mail from Batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, email-client

We have a script to backup files. After the backup operation is over, we would like to send a report as an email notification to some of our email addresses.

How could this be done?

Comment: I'm confused. He's asking how to send email from a batch file. How is that not a programming question?

Comment: damned it' batch and not bash, forget my comment

Comment: How is that offensive? Explain!

Comment: Why not use the task scheduler? Afaik it can do such a thing.

Comment: @Johannes: You should write that as an answer, it deserves some vote.

Comment: @divo: I would imagine it was flagged offensive before you edited out the plzsendtehcodez part.

Answer (score 38):

[Blat](http://www.blat.net/):

```
blat -to user@example.com -server smtp.example.com -f batch_script@example.com -subject "subject" -body "body"
```

Comment: if you want to send emails to multiple addresses then use command like this blat -to "user1@example.com","user2@example.com"

Answer (score 21):

You can also use a Power Shell script:

```
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.example.com")

if( $Env:SmtpUseCredentials -eq "true" ) {
    $credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
    $smtp.Credentials = $credentials
}
$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$objMailMessage.From = "script@mycompany.com"
$objMailMessage.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com")
$objMailMessage.Subject = "eMail subject Notification"
$objMailMessage.Body = "Hello world!"

$smtp.send($objMailMessage)
```

Comment: upvoted. But if you don't want to make a `.ps1`, [you can call it straight from batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38604180/2518317)

Comment: The question was about BATCH, not powershell. Poweshell supports only W7 and later

Answer (score 15):

[PowerShell comes with a built in command for it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx). So running directly from a `.bat` file:

```powershell
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage ^
    -SmtpServer server.address.name ^
    -To someone@what.ever ^
    -From noreply@possibly.fake ^
    -Subject Testing ^
    -Body 123
```

<sub>**NB** `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` is only needed if you haven't set up permissions for running PS from CMD</sub>

<sub>Also for those looking to call it from within powershell, drop everything before `-Command` [inclusive], and `` ` `` will be your escape character (not `^`)</sub>

Comment: As a side note don't forget that when you run something like `powershell  -Command Send-MailMessage...` it needs to be ran with surrounding double quotes and single quotes such as `powershell -Command "Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 'server.address.name' -To 'someone@what.ever' -From 'noreply@possibly.fake' -Subject 'This is a test' -Body 'BLAH BLAH BLAH'"`

Comment: the above worked fine for me, does yours not work without them? Is it because you use have spaces in the subject and require single quotes?

Comment: Possibly, but I could not get it to work without the double quotes for me.  I ran across the suggestion from others experiencing the same problem.  Figured I would share incase someone else hit the same wall.  Even so usually all my Subjects and Bodies in my emails contain spaces.  ;)  - Side note, maybe it has to do with the fact my command is all on one line as opposed to yours the is multiline?

Answer (score 8):

[bmail](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm). Just install the EXE and run a line like this:

```
bmail -s myMailServer -f Sender@foo.com -t receiver@foo.com -a "Production Release Performed"
```

Comment: Here I cant install bamil as per security purpose. plz tell me is there any alernate way to solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried with other command-line email clients? A Google search lists quite many freely available tools.

Answer (score 3):

We use blat to do this all the time in our environment.  I use it as well to connect to Gmail with [Stunnel](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/blat/files/Other/).  Here's the params to send a file

```
blat -to user@example.com -server smtp.example.com -f batch_script@example.com -subject "subject" -body "body" -attach c:\temp\file.txt
```

Or you can put that file in as the body

```
blat c:\temp\file.txt -to user@example.com -server smtp.example.com -f batch_script@example.com -subject "subject"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods for handling this problem.

My advice is to use the powerful Windows freeware console application [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/).

```
sendEmail.exe -f sender.from@mail.com -o message-file=body.txt -u subject message -t to.email.address@mail.com -a attachment.zip -s smtp.gmail.com:446 -xu gmail.login -xp gmail.password
```