# SQL Script (CronJob) with Mail

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have to write a script, that runs ones a day and checks in a SQL Server database for the birthday of customers. And if they have birthday the script will send a personal mail (name etc.) to this person.

**my problems**:
The SQL-part is no problem, but I have no idea how to work with scripts/cronjobs whatever. Which *language* I should use and how to send mails with scripts.

Comment: what os you are using ?

Comment: I forgot to say that it is a 2012 R2 Windows Server with MS SQL 2014 Express.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux cron jobs setup**

Take a look of how to work with **cron jobs** [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

To send emails take a look at [this article](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/#).

Basically your flow to resolve problem above would be next:

- write bash script which talk to `sql` and send email if needed with one of command in article provided above.
- schedule daily or hourly execution of that script in cronjobs.

That's all. Links above contain all requested by you information.

**Windows "cron jobs" setup**

The windows equivalent to a cron job is a scheduled task. There are use full instruction of how to [schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) on official site ( i am sure that for Windows Servers steps would be quite the same).

So you need to create windows script witch would dial with `sql` and send email and than schedule script execution as task. See [Guide to Windows Batch Scriptiong](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/) for details of how to write DOS-style batch files. Also take a look on  [How to send a simple email from a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038926/how-to-send-a-simple-email-from-a-windows-batch-file), here you could find working suggestion of how to add code which sends email from windows script file.

**Alternative**

You could consider using [Pycron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pycron/) which is a clone of the well-known cron job scheduler linux flavored operating systems, the implementation is platform-independant, so you could install it and use on Windows.