# Thunderbird reply using command line

Tags: command-line, thunderbird, reply

I am searching for a way to reply to an e-mail using Thunderbird via command line.

I know where the eml is (let's say `c:\1\test.eml`) and I want to open it using the command line in reply mode (possibly reply all) and insert text based on the users choice from our system.

Comment: Hi @Juice. Welcome! This is an interesting idea I would quite like to know the answer to myself :) Could you share any existing commands you have tried to run?

Comment: Hi @tjheslin1. Thanks for the welcome. No luck so far. Couldnt find any documentation regarding this sort of command line option. I got the basics [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29) and i can build up a mail from our system with attachments and everything, but thats as far as i got.

Comment: Do you have any reason for trying to use a GUI program for batch processing? It could be easier to do that in Python or PowerShell... IMHO you should also have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9038926/3545273)

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta. Its not realy a batch process. Most our e-mails that need to be sent out are unique, but can be categorised about 10 ways. Each category has a 70%-80% text that is basicly a copy-paste part, but needs some unique touch, based on the mail that needs to be reply and 90% of the mais hass attachment.