# Sending email with blat does not work even with stunnel

Tags: email, batch-file, syntax, stunnel, blat

I've been looking everywhere for this answer and have had no luck! I went to http://www.jeffkastner.com/2010/01/blat-stunnel-and-gmail/ and followed it step by step. Stunnel installed, installed service and started service successfully but blat still does not work after setting it up.

I have a folder on my desktop C:\Users\Nicholas\Desktop\Games which is where the contents of blat is placed, and C:\Users\Nicholas\Desktop\Games\stunnel is where stunnel files are installed. And I also tried this when stunnel was installed to program files and it still did not work. I don't want blat installed to system32 because I have a batch file I'm using it with in C:\Users\Nicholas\Desktop\Games.

Online I try to find syntax for the blat -install but none of them work or at least I dont understand how it works. This is what I believe:

1. You need to install your profile
2. You send an email using the profile (ex: blat -p gmailsmtp ...)
   And thats it? It doesn't work for me.

I am willing to find an alternative to blat, but if you give an alternative please give a tutorial, not a suggestion.

Here are the install commands for blat I tried: (Which one should be working?)

```
blat -install smtp.gmail.com

blat -install smtp.gmail.com myemail@gmail.com -u username(does this include @gmail.com?) -pw password – - gmailsmtp
```

Here are email commands I tried:

```
blat -p gmailsmtp -to myemail@gmail.com -subject "subject text" -body "Body text" -server 127.0.0.1:1099
```

and a lot more commands that I can't remember.

Anyway, anyone find where I tripped here?

Comment: No error messages were given in your attempts?  Here's another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709635/sending-mail-from-batch-file

Comment: Yes excuse me, is "SMTP server set to smtp.gmail.com on port 127.0.0.1:1099 with user , retry 1 time(s)" an error message? With "blat -to mail@example.com -server smtp.gmail.com -f mail@example.com -subject "subject" -body "body"" it returns "-to does not exist". But adding "Note.txt" following "blat" returns this and I do not know why... Sending stdin.txt (why not note.txt?) to myemail@example.com. Login name is myemail@example.com. Error: Can't resolve service.Error: Not a socket.

Comment: A quick search resulted in http://blog.frogslayer.com/sending-an-email-through-google-smtp-via-windows-command-line/ which might have more information.  Also the comments there may be useful.

Comment: Thank you @user4317867 , but sadly no luck. I think my computer is trying to connect to port 25 and I know it is blocked, I heard it needs to run through port 465, but how? If all fails, does anyone have a vbscript that can send a simple email? Trust me, I'll make any alternative for a batch script as long as it doesn't bring up a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I found a vbscript script that finally worked! On this thread, "[Email sending not working](http://community.qlik.com/thread/25067)", Miguel posted the following script

`Sub SendGMail()`

' Object creation
`Set objMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")` 
`Set msgConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")`

' Server Configuration
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2`
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"`
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465`
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1` 
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "user@gmail.com"` 
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"`
`msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1`
`msgConf.Fields.Update`

' Email
`objMsg.To = "user@gmail.com"` 
`objMsg.From = "fromuser@domain.com"`
`objMsg.Subject = "Test send with Gmail account"`
`objMsg.HTMLBody = "HTML/Plain text message."` 
`objMsg.Sender = "Mr. Name"`

`Set objMsg.Configuration = msgConf`

' Send
`objMsg.Send`

' Clear
`Set objMsg = nothing`
`Set msgConf = nothing`

`End Sub`

This script is working, but a lot of people still had problems, looking closer into the script I realized I didn't even recall the `SendGMail()`! To make this work I simply typed `SendGMail()` on the next line and BAM! I got an email! Thank you @user4317867 for helping me find my answer.

Comment: Happy to help, you can execute a script on the command line using `CSCRIPT.EXE` more help here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx